# license_finder equivalent for Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a license_finder equivalent for Objective C code, to perform license usage on the code

Refer: 
https://rubygems.org/gems/license_finder/

Comment: how are you managing your dependencies? license_finder does have (experimental) support at least for CocoaPods < 0.39.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more closely, I saw that there already was a stale, open PR on license_finder to add carthage support as well.

I went ahead and brought it up to date with a new PR. Once this is merged, license_finder will support both, CocoaPods (< 0.39) and carthage, so it should work with mostly all current iOS projects. Since you were specifically asking for Objective-C I'm assuming you don't need support for Swift's package manager.

Until the PR is merged, you can install the gem from the PR branch:

```rb
gem 'license_finder', github: 'dmrschmidt/LicenseFinder', branch: 'carthage_support'
```